# OWLViz not displaying diagram centrally

Tags: graphviz, protege

[View of Protege/OWLViz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RqIz.png)I have just installed Protege v5 and opened the Pizza ontology.  The OWLViz visualisation is showing at the top left corner.  Nothing I seem to do will centralise the OWLViz view (see attached.)

have tried help, which points me to this:
https://github.com/protegeproject/owlviz

googled, looked down the list of Stack Overflow OWLViz question, tried ChatGPT!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue just now and found my answers here: https://github.com/protegeproject/owlviz/issues/19

Basically you need to install Graphviz from here https://graphviz.org/download/ . Then open **Protege -> File -> Preferences -> OWLViz**, change **Path to DOT** accordingly to where you installed Graphviz and restart Protege.
Be particularly careful with the path and you should be set.

Comment: Good day to you, our Machine Overlord! For the future, greetings in the posts on Stack Overflow are discouraged. You can learn more here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts